# Array in C++ 11

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

How to use aggregate initialization as the following line gives me error (expected `;`)

```
 std::array<int, 5> i_array1{ {3, 4, 5, 1, 2} };
```

However I am able to compile following line of code

```
std::array<int, 5> a2 = {3, 2, 1,10,12};
```

I am trying to getting used to new array container.
I am using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.
Looking for any help.
Regards

Comment: The first version is fine. Perhaps your compiler does not fully support C++11.

Comment: IIRC, this was not fully implemented in VS2012. It compiles in VS2013

Comment: How to make compiler to support that?

Comment: You cannot make a compiler support that. You can only upgrade to VS2013 which afaik does support this properly.

Comment: @AliKazmi Unless you work at Microsoft on their compiler, and can make a private patch to the VS2012 compiler, then you can't. The only way to get better support is to upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: If you can, upgrade to VS2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368(v=vs.120).aspx) that Visual Studio 2012 does not support initialiser lists but 2013 does.

Comment: This is wrong. `std::array` is an aggregate and doesn't use `initializer_list`s.